# Conditional Required attribute based on generic type in c#

Tags: c#, .net, oop

I have a base class "BASE" and another class "RAN" which is a parent of 5 classes "RAN1", "RAN2", ..., "RAN5".

```
public class RAN {
}
public class RAN1 : RAN {
}
. // RAN2
. // RAN3
. // RAN4
public class RAN5 : RAN {
}

public class BASE<T> where T : RAN {
    [Required]
    public int Myprop {
       get{...}
       set{...}    
    }
}
```

I want this property "Myprop" to be "required" when T equals RAN2 or RAN4.
And this property "Myprop" should be set as "not required" when T equals RAN1, RAN3, RAN5.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: There are no conditional attributes. If you want only some types to have that attribute, you need to specify it on those types

Answer (score 1):

We can try to let `Myprop` property be `virtual` then we can try to override in `RAN2` and `RAN4` and add `Required` attribute for that, other RANs just inherit from `RAN`

```
public class RAN {
    public virtual int Myprop { get; set;}
}

public class RAN1 : RAN {
}

public class RAN2 : RAN {
    [Required]
    public override int Myprop { get; set;}
}

public class RAN4 : RAN {
    [Required]
    public override int Myprop { get; set;}
}
```

Comment: `Myprop` isn't a property of `RAN` though. It's a property of a different `class`, `BASE<T> where T : RAN` that should be required or optional based on the type of `T`.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to write a custom validation attribute to make something like this work. [This page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-6.0#custom-attributes) discusses writing custom attributes. There is also [this older page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/cc668224(v=vs.100)) that might have some relevant or useful information.

For example, you could write something like `RequiredIfClassHasGenericTypeAttribute` by inheriting `RequiredAttribute` and overriding the protected `IsValid(object, ValidationContext`) method.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Somenamespace
{
   public class RequiredIfClassHasGenericTypeAttribute : RequiredAttribute
   {
      public RequiredIfClassHasGenericTypeAttribute(params Type[] requiredGenericTypes)
      {
         RequiredGenericTypes = requiredGenericTypes;
      }

      protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
      {
         var instance = validationContext.ObjectInstance;
         var instanceType = instance.GetType();
         if (instanceType.GenericTypeArguments.Intersect(RequiredGenericTypes).Any())
         {
            var result = base.IsValid(value, validationContext);
            return result;
         }
         return ValidationResult.Success;
      }

      private Type[] RequiredGenericTypes { get; }
   }
}
```

Then you would use it like this...

```
public class BASE<T> where T : RAN
{
   [RequiredIfClassHasGenericType(typeof(RAN2), typeof(RAN4))]
   public int MyProp { get; set; }
}
```

It might also be worth mentioning that the [`RequiredAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.requiredattribute?view=net-6.0) states in the remarks that:

> The RequiredAttribute attribute specifies that when a field on a form is validated, the field must contain a value. A validation exception is raised if the property is null, contains an empty string (""), or contains only white-space characters.

An `int` will never be `null`, contain an empty `string`, or contain only white-space characters so I'm not sure that `RequiredAttribute` will ever fail for an `int`.